# vitest crypto.randomUUID() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, svelte, vitest

### vite.config.ts

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

const config = {
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    test: {
        include: ['**/*.spec.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,mts,cts,jsx,tsx}'],
        environment: 'jsdom',
        globals: true,
        setupFiles: 'src/setupTests.ts'
    }
};

export default config;
```

### src/setupTests.ts

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
```

### MyComponent.svelte

```
onMount(() => {
    postElementId = crypto.randomUUID();
    ...
});
```

### Error

```
TypeError: crypto.randomUUID is not a function
```

> I've got a component that uses the crypto api to create a random id and works as intended, but when I want to test it, everytime I do this error pops up, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My vitest error was `window.crypto.randomUUID() is not a function`.

So, I added `setupFiles` to vite.config.js

```
test: {
    setupFiles: [
        './test/_setup/globalSetup.js'
    ],
...
```

Then, in `globalSetup.js` file I added these 2 lines:

```
import {randomUUID} from 'node:crypto';
window.crypto.randomUUID = randomUUID;
```

And it seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Currently (May 5, 2023), the 'jsdom' environment is missing some crypto functionality, resulting in this error.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1612) for this on the [jsdom Github repo](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom), including [a welcome](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1612#issuecomment-249441408) from one of the maintainers for folks to submit a PR. There are also several workarounds listed there that may work. 

Specifically for vitest, Predrag's answer here is an awesome workaround in the interim - please upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Just checking, did you:

`import crypto from 'node:crypto';`

at some point?

Comment: No, I'm using the built-in API :)

Comment: Yes, `environment: 'jsdom'` indicates a browser, not a nodejs environment.  I'm experiencing this too.